# rand()%100 выдаёт число больше 100

Tags: winapi, c++

Почему функция rand()%100 выдаёт числа больше 100. Раньше такого не наблюдал, во всяком случае в консольных вариантах. Здесь пытался вывести в MessageBox загаданное число.

```
srand(time(0));
int c_train=rand()%100;
wchar_t buffer[30];
char buffer_c[20];  
string value;
string title="Значение: ";
title=title+itoa(c_train,buffer_c,8);       
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,title.c_str(),-1,buffer,30);
MessageBox(NULL, buffer,  _T("Win32 Guided Tour"), NULL);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А все правильно выводит. Ответ в строке

```
itoa(c_train,buffer_c,8);
```

а именно в числе 8. Вы просите выводить в системе счисления по базе 8. Поэтому 64 уже будет выглядеть как 100.

Comment: 64  выдаёт всевозможные буковки и символы

Comment: если вместо 8 написать 64, да... будет такое выдавать:) 10 нужно там писать.

Comment: Подозревал. А можно узнать пояснение по поводу этого 3 параметра. Что оно устанавливает? А то на аглицком так и не понял.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 7):

Потому, что вы выводите число в восьмеричной системе исчисления (третий параметр в itoa).

Comment: пробовал разные но только 8 выдавало более менее адекватные значения. остальные и буковки выдают и цифорки.

Comment: @Димка, вам бы не программированием, а реверс-инжинирингом заниматься.

Comment: А что это такое? :)))
Или это о том как я конвертироал значения? :)))

Comment: @Димка "пробовал разные" это пять конечно) То есть Вы не в курсе что такое системы исчисления?

Comment: Как ни странно, но в курсе. :))))
Просто "запарился".